# css margin collision

Tags: css, margin

Is there a way to detect margin-collision and prevent it? like if I have

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
<div style="margin-top: 10px;"></div>
```

I get 20px space between them, but I need 10px instead?

Comment: If that's the only styling in play, browsers rendering in Standards Mode *should* display that as only 10px. Perhaps you're seeing 20px if you haven't properly set a doctype that would enable standards mode?

Comment: But this gives you 10px, http://jsfiddle.net/TjYEa/

Comment: @Scott: I checked; margin collapse occurs in quirks mode on IE6. @sidyll: Yes I've already provided a fiddle for that :)

Comment: @BoltClock that's what happens when you don't refresh the page after typing in jsFiddle :)

Comment: @BoltClock: Huh, interesting. @Guy: Under what conditions are you seeing 20? (What browser, OS, and version of each?)

Comment: Actually, the situation is that the first element is <table> and the second is <div>. It still doesn't work, even though in situation as I posed this question it does work.

Comment: @Guy: I edited my answer to explain why you're not seeing it for table and div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to do anything; by the box model specs, adjacent bottom and top margins will [collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins), so you get a 10-pixel gap between your two `<div>` elements as opposed to a 20-pixel gap. See [this jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/4ZzfL).

**EDIT:** the reason why you're not seeing a collapse between a `<table>` ad a `<div>` is because a table is set to `display: table` by default, which is not exactly the same as a block-level element, so by the specs the margins will not collapse.

Comment: +1 for linking the spec. @Guy, It's generally called margin-collapse.

Comment: the problem is that when I set <table> display: block, I am having problems with columns width. They don't work anymore with width 100%. Any trick I could apply on table that wouldn't require setting it to display: block? and yet, I have an another issue, because margin collision does not work when I have something in between the two elements, like: <div> <script> <div>